# Is it possible to have a border-left completely rounded?

Tags: css, border, border-radius

I'm redoing some of the UI stuff in my app and want to replace the following:
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tQnw.png)

with this:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqkJj.png)

Currently the HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="row required">
<label for="NumericFieldStartKm-numericfield">Kilometer at start</label>
<input id="NumericFieldStartKm-numericfield" value="" class="required numbercontrol mbsc-comp" min="1" max="" readonly="">
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.row.required {
  border-left: 7px solid #C30000;
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 4px !important;
}
```

Of course I could add a div and shape that div as a pill and put that in front of the label and input, but that would require me to change a ton of code. When I make the same change with CSS that saves me hours worth of work so that's why I'd prefer to do it through some CSS magic.

I found a few things regarding the use of ::after or other pseudo elements, but I have no clue if I can even achieve what I'm trying to achieve using CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a `::before` pseudo-element to draw the border.
We use `float: left` for the pseudo-element and set a fixed width for `.row` so that the elements after the floated pseudo-element are stacked vertically.

```css
.row.required {
  width: 200px;
}

.row.required::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-left: 7px solid #C30000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row required">
  <label for="NumericFieldStartKm-numericfield">Kilometer at start</label>
  <input id="NumericFieldStartKm-numericfield" value="" class="required numbercontrol mbsc-comp" min="1" max="" readonly="">
</div>
```

Comment: This will put the border in front of the label, but I want to put the border in front of the entire row. Is that possible as well?

Comment: Did you run the snippet?